# ¿Combinar Dataframes manteniendo las columnas del primero en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

¡Buen día!

Tengo 2 dataframes. El DF_X tiene las columnas A y B y el DF_Y las columnas A,B,C y D.
Quiero que las filas del DF_Y pasen al DF_X, pero solo el contenido de las columnas A y B.

Lo fácil era usar el merge tras eliminar las columnas C y D en el DF_Y. Pero debido al trabajo que tengo que realizar, este proceso es muy poco óptimo.

¿Hay alguna forma elegante de decir que las filas del DF_Y pasen al DF_X SOLO EN las columnas que existen en DF_X sin tener que hacer pasos previos o eliminar las columnas después en DF_X?

Pongo ejemplo:

DF_X:

```
    A     B
---------------
    1     R
    4     T
    2     Y
```

DF_Y

```
    A     B    C    D
-------------------------
    3     G    2    4
    6     E    1    T
    1     W    4    Y
```

Resultado deseado:

DF_X

```
   A     B
---------------
    1     R
    4     T
    2     Y
    3     G    
    6     E    
    1     W
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver mediante [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects) y seleccionado primero las columnas de `DF_Y` que se encuentren en `DF_X`:

```
pd.concat([DF_X, DF_Y[DF_X.columns]])
```

Comment: ¿Será DF_Y[DF_X.columns]?

Comment: @CandidMoe, gracias!

Comment: Esta es la forma más sencilla. Pensé hacer un outer join, pero le traería también las columnas C y D, después se podrían eliminar, pero tu solución es mucho mejor.